# Create a Database from Script Runtime

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

I have a T-SQL script to create a Database. I need to create this database runtime. When the application is Running.

What Connection String do I use?

How do I connect to the server and Create the Database? I am connecting to the server as a Network user. I am not using User "sa" I have a user "DBCreator"

My application is in C#.

I have this Script in T-SQL:

```
USE [master]
GO

CREATE DATABASE [XYZ]
-- Table Creation Code etc.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have two connection strings. One for master database to issue the CREATE DATABASE ... statement and another one for database created.

```
// You can use replace windows authentication with any user credentials who has proper permissions.
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"server=(local);database=master;Integrated Security=SSPI"))
{
    connection.Open();

    using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = "CREATE DATABASE [XYZ]";
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}

// Quering the XYZ database created
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"server=(local);database=XYZ;Integrated Security=SSPI"))
{
    connection.Open();

    using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = "select * from sys.objects";
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [SMO](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx) objects to do that. I don't think i should explain what is already explained in details in a very good tutorial [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/127065/SMO-Tutorial-1-of-n-Programming-data-storage-objec#CreatingDB)

Comment: see the link i have posted.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely use SMO its intended to do everything that SSMS can do, and more! it actually has a command called Database.Create(), follow this MSDN [page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms205154.aspx)